# Extraneous text in resource files

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am getting a extraneous text in resource files error in my xml layout file in android studio caused by
the tools context. I am not sure how to correct this error. Any tips would be appreciated?

```
`tools:context=".MainActivity`
```

Comment: can you share layout file

Comment: it should be `tools:context=".MainActivity"`

Comment: great @leo your issue resolved. Please accept and vote answer so that others can get benefit from your question.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
`tools:context=".MainActivity`
```

It should be:

```
tools:context=".MainActivity"
```